# How do you Identify apps or procs that create large tmp files?

Tags: filesystem

I am having problems when using GNS3 on a Win7 host running a VMware Workstation Ubuntu VM.
Not sure what app or process is creating large 3+GB temp files filing up my drive.
How can tell. Below is after removing the 2 large files.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        21G  7.2G   13G  37% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            2.4G  4.0K  2.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           493M  1.4M  491M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.5G  156K  2.5G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   56K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Answer (score 1):

Some spontaneous ideas how to track the origin of those files:

- Look at the names of the temporary files. Many programs choose names that allow you to infer their origin.
- Look for processes with open references to them with [`fuser(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/fuser.1) or [`lsof(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/lsof.8).
- Look for suspicious log entries around the last time of modification of the large temporary files either in the system logs or logs of applications you suspect.